# Laptop brightness and contrast drastically changing when unplugged

Tags: windows-8, display, laptop-repair

Whenever my laptop is plugged in, it works perfectly fine. However, when I unplug it, the screen starts changing drastically in contrast and brightness until I plug the laptop back in. I replaced the laptop screen recently because the last one was cracked, but I doubt that's the problem since it works fine when plugged in. I included a video of what happens when I unplug the screen (It's obvious when I unplug it and plug it back in).

http://tinypic.com/r/118m34y/8

What could be causing this? I tried changing power-saving options between balanced and high performance, but it didn't change anything. I've been advised to go change the display settings in the Intel Control Panel, but when I right-click on my desktop there is no option for Graphics Settings. I have no idea what could be doing this...should I return the laptop screen I bought, or is it a computer software issue?

Here's some diagnosing I have already done in an attempt to narrow it down:

- When I use an external monitor only the screen on the laptop acts as shown in the video.
- When entering boot-mode during start-up, unplugging does not affect the screen
- When unplugged, screen remains unaffected until the loading screen for the user login screen appears (and the screen displaying the time before login screen as well)
- Whilst starting up, the boot mode screen and the windows logo loading screen both contain variants of the color blue. This leads me to believe that it isn't just because it's black and white that the screen is unaffected until the loading screen for login, but possibly because it uses a different rendering mode? (Similar to how the "Blue Screen of Death" screen doesn't use the graphics card to render text and color)

That's all I've been able to deduce. I haven't completely ruled out the screen itself as the culprit, but I definitely have my doubts about it. On one hand, it doesn't act strange until after start up leading me to believe that it's a graphics issue. On the other hand, external monitors aren't affected by this problem so it *could* be the screen...I just don't know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22012/discussion-on-question-by-thenewguy-laptop-brightness-and-contrast-drastically-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. After ordering a new laptop screen with no success fixing the issue, I suspected the LCD Cable may the issue, as the pin connected fit rather loosely into the screen and was easy to knock out. Sure enough, after replacing the LCD Cable the issue was fixed and the laptop is good as new!

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS settings.  Some BIOS's will dim the screen when not plugged in.

Comment: Speculative suggestions and helpful hints should really be a comment.  Save answers for definitive solutions.

Comment: @fixer1234 Everything is speculation, until the OP tests it.

Comment: Correct, and then you are able to provide a definitive answer.  That's the problem with troubleshooting questions, nobody can provide a proper answer until some point when the OP figures it out, and then doesn't need one.  Some good discussion here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6837/are-diagnostics-troubleshooting-issues-on-topic-and-not-too-localized